# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getApiClient() from the type BaseGameActivity

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I'm working on implementing Play Game Services in a game and I keep running into a problem when trying to submit the score from the gamePanel to the leaderboard. I cannot run the method anywhere except my GameActivity which extends BaseGameActivity if i try to call it somewhere else i get the error above.

method to submit score

```
public class GameActivity extends BaseGameActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
static void updatePlayThingies(){
    int distance= MainGamePanel.Squirrel.getDist();
    if(gameover==true){
        Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(), "Leaderboard_id", distance);
    }
```

}

game logic that needs to call updatePlayThingies

```
public class Squirrel{
private int distance = 0;
public void phys(){
 if (speedx==0){
bouncecheck=0;
//ball stopped
//reset stats and move ball back to launcher
GameActivity.gameover=true;
GameActivity.paused=true;
    GameActivity.updatePlayThingies();
}
}
```

Comment: getApiClient is accessible only in classes that extends BaseGameActivity.

Comment: Why don't you search for "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method". There are so many questions about it, read the answers ad it will give you complete understanding of what you are trying to do and why it does not work.

Comment: I am running the game logic in a thread and the only way to call it from my game activity is to make updateplaythiniges static which breaks that code or construct a new game activity in my thread which doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
static void updatePlayThingies(GoogleApiClient apiClient){
    int distance= MainGamePanel.Squirrel.getDist();
    if(gameover==true){
        Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(apiClient, "CgkIkfSPtJocEAIQAQ", distance);
    }
```

And call updatePlayThingies like tis:

```
updatePlayThinges(getApiClient());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
static void updatePlayThingies(){
int distance= MainGamePanel.Squirrel.getDist();
if(gameover==true){
    Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(
      newGoogleApiClient().getApiClient(), 
      "CgkIkfSPtJocEAIQAQ", distance);
}
```